# What am I doing wrong with inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass

I'm trying to write simple game to test some new features in Java. I have Class Monsters and there is int hp:

```
public class Monsters {
    int hp;

    public Monsters() {
    }
    public Monsters(int hp) {
        this.hp = hp;
    }
    }
```

And then I have two subclasses - a main hero HERO, and his oponent Devil. They also have int hp, because their life level is different:

```
public class Devil extends Monsters {

    int hp = 200;
}
```

and HERO:

```
    public class HERO extends Monsters{
    public HERO(int hp) {
        this.hp = hp;
    }
    }
```

I'm trying to write fight(); method:

```
public void fight(Monsters hero) {
        int heroLife = hero.hp;
        int opLife = hp;
        System.out.println(opLife + " - Devil's life\n"
                + heroLife + " - Hero's life");
}
```

Ok, and now in main() class Game i'm testing their hp:

```
public class Gra {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   HERO hero = new HERO(5);
   Devil devil = new Devil();
   devil.fight(hero);
   }
}
```

And here's my output:

```
0 - Devil's life
5 - Hero's life
```

Why is it 0, not 200?

Comment: I suggest that your `Monsters` class should be called `Monster`, since each instance of the class represents an individual.

Comment: @khelwood ok, i'm going to change it

Comment: Maybe call `Monster` the base class that both heroes and villains are inheriting it's not the right choice. Unless your game characters are only monsters, good and evil monsters :) I agree with the singular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `hp` variable in both `Monsters` class and `Devil` class. When you access `hp` from a method of `Monsters` class (your `filght` method), you get the variable of `hp`, which is 0 by default.

You should have `hp` only in the base class, and use `Monster`'s constructor to initialize it properly :

For example :

```
public class Devil extends Monsters 
{   
    public Devil () 
    {
        super(200);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks :) both solutions work (yours and Tanmay's Patil). However in my project it is better to have hp int in each subclass, e.g. if I want to fight with two monsters simulataneously.

Comment: @MichałGwóźdź What Tanmay suggested it exactly the same as my answer. Putting `this.hp = 200;` in Devil's constructor is the same as passing it to Monsters' constructor with the call to super(200). Both update the `hp` variable in `Monsters` class. The only difference is that if you make `hp` private (which is a good practice in OOP), Tanmay's code wouldn't compile.

Comment: yeah, you are right. When I set int hp to private I get errors in HERO class. I didn't know that this() and super() in this case are doing the same job. I'll choose your solution.

Comment: Another good practice is to use `public` getters and setters, so problem solved! `protected` is also an option for inheritance scope.

Answer (score 3):

### Problem

You are creating new `hp` field and hiding inherited `hp`.

### Solution

Replace

```
public class Devil extends Monsters {

    int hp = 200;
}
```

with

```
public class Devil extends Monsters {
    public Devil() {
        this.hp = 200;
    }
}
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You are not defining default constructor at your devil class. First implement default constructor inside default constructor use super keyword.

```
public class Devil extends Monsters 
{
  public Devil() {
   super();
    this.hp = 200;
  }
}
```

Comment: Either use `super(200)` or just `this.hp` if nothing else is initialized/called in the parents constructor.